# A question on filtered complexes

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

For every complex $K$ in the category of complexes, I need to construct a decreasing filtration of $K$ by subcomplexes $\cdots \supset F^i \supset F^{i+1} \supset \cdots$ such that every factor complex $G^i = F^i/F^{i+1}$ has at most one nonzero cohomology module, which is situated at degree $i$ and is canonically isomorphic to **(a)** $K^i$, and **(b)** $H^i(K)$

I thought the canonical truncation/filtration should work for **(b)** at least, but I'm unable to work the cohomology out of the factor complex in that case. Any help for **(a)** and **(b)** will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed consider the usual truncation, that is, let $F_pK$ be the complex that has $\ker \partial$ in degree $p$, nothing in degrees $>p$, and $K^i$ in degrees $<p$. Then the quotient $F_p/F_{p-1}$ looks like

$$0 \longrightarrow  K_{p-1}/ \ker (\partial_{p-1}) \longrightarrow \ker \partial_p \longrightarrow  0$$

and has indeed homology concentrated in degree $p$ where it is $H^p(K)$. If you instead put $K^p$ in degree $p$, you will get just

$$0 \longrightarrow  0 \longrightarrow K^p \longrightarrow  0.$$